# Broadcast latest data without polling

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a very sensitive application using Oracle 12c, where I need to send a notification to other system whenever there is insert/update on a table. Ways I know to achieve is by

1. polling the table in regular intervals.
2. putting a trigger on the table for insert/update. In both the cases I am worried about the additional load on the database.
3. Replicate the data to another database with GoldenGate and continuously poll from it, so that I don't have to worry about  the overhead.
4. not sure about materialized view.. can it be lightweight if refreshed every 1-2 seconds ?

Is there an programmatic alternative anyone can suggest(lightweight).

Comment: What is the "other system" and how do you communicate with it?

Comment: Are you looking for [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS018)?  Do you need the details of what's changed, or just a notification whenever anything has changed?  If you just need a notification, then a trigger should work fine (although it perhaps couldn't handle rollback).  Also, consider that a replication solution would probably have more overhead than any hacked together solution.

Comment: @OldProgrammer middleware, xml messages over tcp/ip

Comment: @JonHeller thanks for pointing, I am checking on Change Query Notification. I am looking at notification anytime a new row is inserted. then looking at the changed data I decide whether to action.